# Create unique constraint initially disabled

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, unique-constraint, unique-index

This is my table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable] 
(
  [Name1] varchar(50) COLLATE French_CI_AS NOT NULL,
  [Name2] varchar(255) COLLATE French_CI_AS NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [TestTable_uniqueName1] UNIQUE ([Name1]),
  CONSTRAINT [TestTable_uniqueName1Name2] UNIQUE ([Name1], [Name2])
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
ADD CONSTRAINT [TestTable_uniqueName1] 
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Name1])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
ADD CONSTRAINT [TestTable_uniqueName1Name2] 
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Name1], [Name2])
GO

ALTER INDEX [TestTable_uniqueName1]
  ON [dbo].[TestTable]
  DISABLE
GO
```

My idea is to enable/disable one or other unique contraint depending on the customer application. With this way, I can catch the thrown exception in my c# code, and display a specific error message to the GUI.

Now, my problem is to alter the collation of columns `Name1` & `Name2`, I need to make them case sensitive (`French_CS_AS`). To alter these fields, I have to drop the two constraints and recreate it. According to the explained schema, I cannot create an enabled constraint and then disable it, because by some customers, I have duplicate keys for one or other constraint.

For my update script, my idea number 1 was

1. Save the name of enabled constraints in a temp table
2. Drop the constraints
3. Alter columns
4. Create **DISABLED** unique constraints
5. Enable specific constraints according to the saved values in points 1.

My problem is in point 4., I don't find how to create a disabled unique constraint with an `ALTER TABLE` statement. Is it possible to create it directly in the `sys.indexes` table ?

My idea number 2 was

1. Rename TestTable to TestTableCopy
2. Recreate TestTable with the new fields collation, and otherwise the same schema (indexes, FK, triggers, ...)
3. Disable specifical unique contraints in TestTable
4. Migrate data from TestTableCopy to TestTable
5. Drop TestTableCopy

In this way, my fear is to loose some links with other tables/dependencies, beceause it is a central table in my database.

Is there any other way to achieve my goal?

If necessary, I can use unique indexes instead of unique constraints.

Comment: Why can't you forget the Unique constraint and check yourself and catch an exception when adding an record into the table?

Comment: Because records can be inserted from many ways (with t-sql, from my c# application, ...). I want the database to check my data.

Comment: create a stored procedure to insert the records into the table, you can use it for all types the inserts you need. In stored procedure check for the constraint based on what you need. That would the way I would do it. Altering the table is not a good practice.

Comment: So I would need another stored procedure to edit my rows... This way I do not like 100%. Why is it not a best practice to alter a table ? Either way, I could need an alter table to change the length of my varchar column...

Comment: Take a look at my example.

Comment: @stephanejulien it is not clear the requirement behind all this. you want to have one constraint active and one inactive. why? does it relate someway with the change of collation? and..why do you change the collation? create it right at the beginning and you're done, isn't it? there are lots of information missing to get the picture of this unusual requirement... also this requirement implies that the customer chan change 'application' so you may be forced to enable a disabled index. that's quite odd.

Comment: @Paolo My database is not a new one. I have many databases deployed by many customers. And now I have to change the collation to be case sensitive. In an other way, an alter table could be necessary on these fields. The need to change the collation doesn't relate to the constraint activation. I enable/disable these constraints according to the customer specifications. Now I build an update script which have to be compatible with all customer databases.

Comment: @stephanejulien so the requirement is to change the collation and after that 'alter table' you want/need to restore the correct index. is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is impossible to create a unique index on a column that already has duplicate values.

So, rather than having a disabled unique index either:

- not have an index at all (which is the same as having a disabled index from the query processor point of view),
- or create a non-unique index.

For those instanses where your client has unique data create unique index. For those instanses where your client has non-unique data create non-unique index.

Comment: You're right ! I searched in many ways, it's impossible to create a disabled unique constraint or a disabled unique index. My solution is to drop my constraints, alter my columns, and recreate only those who were initially enabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUsers_AddUsers]
@Name1 varchar(50)  ,
@Name2 varchar(50) ,
@Unique bit 
AS

declare @err int
begin tran
    if @Unique = 1 begin
 if not exists (SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name1 = @Name1 and Name2 = @Name2) 
 begin
     INSERT INTO Users (Name1,Name2) 
   VALUES (@Name1,@Name2)
   set @err = @@ERROR
 end else
 begin
   UPDATE Users
   set Name1 = @Name1,
   Name2 = @Name2
   where Name1 = @Name1 and Name2 = @Name2
   set @err = @@ERROR
 end   

end else begin
    if not exists ( SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name1 = @Name1 )
    begin
         INSERT INTO Users (Name1,Name2) 
         VALUES (@Name1,@Name2)
        set @err = @@ERROR
    end else
    begin
    UPDATE Users
     set Name1 = @Name1,
         Name2 = @Name2
     where Name1 = @Name1 
     set @err = @@ERROR
end


 if @err = 0 commit tran
    else rollback tran
```

So first you check if you need an unique Name1 and Name2 or just Name1. Then if you do you an insert/update based on what constrain you have.

Comment: I understand your approach, but I will consider it only if I can not change my table. All my database is designed with contraints, and I think that it is not a bad way.

Comment: It's not, I use constraints all the time, and they are an very important part in every db, but your situation seems a bit strage, and I have never encounter it (having to change the constraint everytime).